# How to permanently deny Google Talk Plugin?

Tags: internet-explorer, gmail

In Internet Explorer, i get this confounded popup every time i sign into Gmail. Yes, of course Google wants to install something on my computer, and i ignore it or click "x" each and every time. The combo box only gives the option to Allow or Allow for all websites. How can i **permanently** deny this? I don't want more uneccessary Google junk.

[image: Help me deny Google]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the "Google Talk plugin" from Control Panel-->Programs-->Uninstall a program should do the trick if you don't use google talk at all.

More info here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=0ef9f1331f105dee&hl=en